# Split citation into author and year

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

I have this in my `.tex`:

```
This study was done by \cite{mogul1997potential} in X and lately proposed to be 
a present feature in HTTP servers \cite{mogul2002delta}.
```

It generates:

> This study was done by [Mogul et al. 1997] in X and lately proposed to
>   be a present feature in HTTP servers [Mogul et al. 2002].

I want to split the citation into two parts, the author and the year as you can see. How do I do that? Example:

> This study was done by Mogul et al. in 1997 and lately proposed to be
>   a present feature in HTTP servers [Mogul et al. 2002].

I am using [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/do0z9glmmb6em85/modelosparapublicaodeartigos.rar) template. Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{sbc-template}
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\sloppy

\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{bb a a}
\author{Frederico Schardong\inst{1}}
\address{aa aa aa \email{aa@aa.aa}}

\begin{document} 

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Hi
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
This study was done by \cite{mogul1997potential} in X and lately proposed to be 
a present feature in HTTP servers \cite{mogul2002delta}.

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{sbc}
\bibliography{sbc-template}

\end{document}
```

and this would be my references file:

```
@article{mogul2002delta,
  title={Delta encoding in HTTP},
  author={Mogul, Jeffrey and Krishnamurthy, Balachander and Douglis, Fred and Feldmann, Anja and Goland, Yaron and van Hoff, Arthur and Hellerstein, D},
  journal={Work in Progress},
  year={2002}
}

@inproceedings{mogul1997potential,
  title={Potential benefits of delta encoding and data compression for HTTP},
  author={Mogul, Jeffrey C and Douglis, Fred and Feldmann, Anja and Krishnamurthy, Balachander},
  booktitle={ACM SIGCOMM Computer Communication Review},
  volume={27},
  number={4},
  pages={181--194},
  year={1997},
  organization={ACM}
}
```

Comment: This can be done.  Please provide a complete minimal example document of how you are using BibTeX for others to modify.

Comment: @jon, thanks for the comment, just added the code

Comment: `sbc-template` is not a standard package: please provide a link

Comment: With your bibliography style you can't do this. The style doesn't support `\citeyear` nor `\citeauthor`. You can use `biblatex` or `natbib` whereby I recommend `biblatex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the comment your style file doesn't support your request. Packages like `natbib` or `biblatex` are supporting `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` for such issues.

However I recommend the usage of `biblatex`.